# JavaFX - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Morning/Afternoon

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Splash.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Title");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Splash.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <top>
      <ImageView fitHeight="96.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Hangman.png" />
         </image>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="50.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </ImageView>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="15.0">
         <children>
            <TextField maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" promptText="Username" />
            <TextField layoutX="236.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" promptText="Password" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#testClick" text="Enter" />
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Pane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="279.0" text="Sign Up">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Controller

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.util.Random;

public class Controller {

    public void testClick() {

        System.out.println("test");
    }



}
```

I'm getting the error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException". Spent hours trawling through forums. The produce the FXML code I used Scene Builder and everything SEEMS to be in working order. Where is the issue coming from? and how can I stop it in the future?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should post the exception in the first place. But I suspect that your problems may come from using the Gluon `TextField`?

Comment: It seems that was right! Remove it and it loaded, why is this error happening?

Comment: Because you are adding the wrong `TextField`: Unless you are creating a Gluon mobile project, your JavaFX desktop application doesn't have the Gluon Mobile library included.

Comment: Thank you José, much appreciated! :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, it could be useful to others as well

Answer (score 1):

If you check the list of imports in your FXML file you have:

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
...
```

So unless you are creating a Gluon [Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gluon-mobile) project, your JavaFX application will not include the Gluon Mobile library, and it will fail to find the `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField` control, throwing the `InvocationTargetException`.

You just need to use the JavaFX built-in control, from the Controls tab:

[image]